# How can I write a script to firefox that works with the adressbar?

Tags: firefox, scripting, firefox-addon

I want to write a script to firefox that in the moment I start to write address in the addressbar it change the language to the one I'll choose (in the add-on).How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by "change the language to the one I'll choose" you mean changing the OS input language, you'd do it by:

- [Learning the basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension)
- [Searching for details of working with the Location bar](http://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+extension+location+bar+event) and reviewing [previous answers on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186418/responding-to-address-bar-key-events-in-firefox-add-on)
- Finally, for actually switching the input language you'll have to talk to the OS directly, there's no API in the platform for that. You could use [ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/ctypes.jsm) for that if you developed for future Firefox versions; otherwise you'd have to write an XPCOM component in C++ (which is more complicated) or resort to launching an external program for that (which would probably not work well).